# Binding to property within the ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have class like the following:

```
class test
{
  public string Name;
  public string Location;
}
```

Through a result of query using entity framework I am getting back a collection of test objects which I am directly setting to my listbox. But using the DisplayMemberPath Iam just displaying Name value. So now the listbox is holding the whole collection of test objects but just displaying Name value.

When I am trying to bind to the selecteditem of the list box Iam getting the whole test object as a string but I just need Name value in the selecteditem result.

My XAML is as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbSubSelector" Height="200" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

My code to populate list is as follows:

```
 LoadOperation<test> subLoadOp = context.Load(context.GetTestQuery());
 lbSubSelector.ItemsSource = subLoadOp.Entities;
 lbSubDistrictSelector.DataContext = SkillModel.Instance;
```

The DataContext to which the selectedItem is set to is having a value of the whole string representation of test object but I want the selecteditem to just return Name value as it is displaying (as i have set the displaymemberpath to Name) instead of returned the whole object in string format.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you need to read about SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath properties of a [listbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx).

Comment: @stukselbax, you need to post this comment as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbSubSelector" Height="200" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="@Name" />
```

Then you can use **lbSubSelector.SelectedValue** to get Name property of selected item.

see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please use the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property on the Listbox and change the SelectedItem binding to /Name in xaml code as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbSubSelector" Height="200" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding /Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than Using ListBox, I would suggest you using the ListView with GridColumns. Following is the snippet, you might need to remodify it accordingly. But this surely will work the way you want it to :-

```
<ListView Name="ListView1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" MouseDoubleClick="transactionListView_MouseDoubleClick" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource gridViewHeaderColumnStyle}">
                            <GridView.Columns>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Width="270" Header="Seller" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Location}" />
                            </GridView.Columns>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```